# R: How to create a loop that copies every four columns and create a new csv

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I'm working with this script but I need to help to do this loop.

So, I have two dataframes with these data:

```
    > print(df1)
# A tibble: 278 x 476
       X__3  X__4  X__5  X__6     X__7
      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>
 1 21340.59   446  1456   278 23682.23
 2 33830.18   706  1729   386 40571.88
 3 37470.65   765  2783   404 36837.99
 4 20069.07   401  1850   244 25033.11
 5 25521.06   426  4250   228 26447.16
 6 53233.17  1161  2216   545 52072.19
 7 34075.87   746  5083   375 34782.48
 8 30410.16   653  3688   330 28270.09
 9 61661.07  1193  4611   665 81029.73
10 17801.79   337  1754   192 16907.32
```

And another dataframe (fixa):

```
 > print(fixa)
# A tibble: 278 x 2
    place name
    <chr>    <chr>
 1    AB1  114_AAY
 2    CD1  129_STA
 3    EF1  123_PWA
 4    EF1  135_MXY
 5    AB1  127_AID
 6    CD1  152_STO
 7    GH1  156_MCO
 8    CD1  195_KZS
 9    EF1  190_SLO
10    GH1  197_KYZ
# ... with 268 more rows
```

I need to copy four to four columns (to the end) from "df1" and match the columns of the "fixa" and create a new dataframe "newdf"

```
x <- df1[1:476]
verif <- 1

for (i in x){
  idx = i
  idxEnd = i+3
  i = -i+4
  new[verif] <- cbind(fixa, df[idx:idxEnd])
  B2csv<-Paste0(newdf[verif], idx, "-", idxEnd,".csv")
  Save.csv(B2csv)
}
```

My output is something like this, but each saved in a csv file:

```
    print(newdf1)
       place name    results       qty     shops
1      AB1  114_AAY  21340.59      446     1456
2      CD1  129_STA  33830.18      706     1729
3      EF1  123_PWA  37470.65      765     2783
4      EF1  135_MXY  20069.07      401     1850
```

But I do not know where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is better provide your expected output

Comment: Wen, I edited the question including the output. Please, look again. Thanks!

Comment: seems like you just need a `cbind`

Comment: Also I think, I even wrote in the code in which I try to make the loop run the 476 columns. But the loop did not work. :(

Comment: `x <- df1[1:476]
verif <- 1

for (i in x){
  idx = i
  idxEnd = i+3
  i = -i+4
  new[verif] <- cbind(fixa, df[idx:idxEnd])
  B2csv<-Paste0(newdf[verif], idx, "-", idxEnd,".csv")
  Save.csv(B2csv)
}`

Comment: your code have multiple typo , this should be work`for (i in seq(1, 476, 3)){
  idx = i
  idxEnd = i+3
  new <- cbind(fixa, df[idx:idxEnd,])
  write.csv(new,paste0(idx, "-", idxEnd,".csv"))
} `

Comment: like Wen said looks like all you need is `cbind`. However, you are defining `verif = 1` then you are calling  `new[verif]` which you have not previously defined, then trying to `paste0` something called `newdf[verif]` that also hasn't been defined nor is it text or a numeric value for `paste0` to use.

Comment: @BWilliams I guess he try to using list to save the dataframe, but seems like it is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! I tried the code but i got this error: 'Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 278, 4'

Comment: A slight edit to a comma placement for the `df[]` subsetting in @Wen's code should do it: `for (i in seq(1, 476, 3)){ idx = i idxEnd = i+3 new <- cbind(fixa, df[,idx:idxEnd]) write.csv(new,paste0(idx, "-", idxEnd,".csv")) }